# Progress bar with a foreach

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

In a foreach, i do sql request. I would like to have a progressbar to show the progress of each request ok.

Here a part of my code who contains the foreach :

```
        private void CUID_allcheckbox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isAnyChecked = 0;
        UID_SendRestore.IsEnabled = false;

        foreach (DBtoRestore item in from DBtoRestore x in dgDBtoRestore.Items select x)
        {
            item.IsChecked = false;
            dgDBtoRestore.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }
    private void UID_SendRestore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Bd_IsUpdate = isAnyChecked;

        if (RestoreDatabase.IsChecked == false && ReorganizeDatabase.IsChecked == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Vous devez sélectionner au minimum un choix à appliquer", "Absence de sélection", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            return;
        }

        foreach (DBtoRestore item in from DBtoRestore x in dgDBtoRestore.Items
                                     where x.IsChecked
                                     select x)
        {

            pbStatus.Maximum = isAnyChecked;
            Bd_IsUpdate--;

            if (RestoreDatabase.IsChecked == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Cnx.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        Cnx.Close();
                    }
                    if (cmbAuthentification.Text.Equals("Windows"))
                    {
                        SQL_Connection.ConnectionString = "Server = " + txtServerName.Text + "; Integrated Security = SSPI;";
                        
                        Cnx.ConnectionString = SQL_Connection.ConnectionString;
                    }
                    else if (cmbAuthentification.Text.Equals("SQL Server"))
                    {
                        SQL_Connection.ConnectionString = "Server = " + txtServerName.Text + "; User ID =" + txtUserID.Text + "; Password=" + txtUserPwd.Password + ";";
                        Cnx.ConnectionString = SQL_Connection.ConnectionString;
                    }
                    Cnx.Open();
                    Cmd.Connection = Cnx;
                    Cmd.CommandText =
                    @"USE [" + item.CUID_dbname + "];" + ...

                    Cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    SqlDataReader dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    Cnx.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "OOoopssss !!!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Hand);
                    Bd_IsUpdate++;
                }
            }
```

I have try many code, but the only result I have is the progressbar full at the end of requests...

Help welcome.

Comment: Your app "hangs" on that `foreach` loop so you can't see running progress, only result when it completes. You should run your job in other thread or asynchroniously. Put whole loop into separated method or Task and run this method through `new Thread().Start()` or `Task.Run`. And add code to set progress bar value into foreach loop.

Comment: Something like that ?

`Task.Run(() =>
{
for (int i = 0; i < pbStatus.Maximum; i++)
{
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
{
pbStatus.Value = i;
});
}
});`

Comment: Yep, but you need to calculate percentage of current progress or set ProgressBar.MaxValue as items count which is checked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `foreach` loop runs in main thread and could "hang" your app until complete. You should run it in other thread (check  `Thread.Start()` and `Task.Run()` methods) to leave app usable and responsive.

For progress updating purposes, you can use `for` loop instead `foreach` loop and:

- use iteration as current value for your progress bar. In that case, you should change `ProgressBar.MaxValue` everytime before looping, depending on items count to iterate.
- calculate percentage instead of direct amounts.

Example 1 (set current iteration of `for` loop as progress bar value):

```
private void YourButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> sqlQueries = new List<string>(10);

    // Set maximum value of your progress bar as
    // amount of items which you will iterate in loop
    progressBar.MaxValue = sqlQueries.Count; // 10
    progressBar.Value = 0; // Reset current value to 0

    // Run loop in other thread
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sqlQueries.Count; i++)
        {
            string sqlQuery = sqlQueries[i];

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    // Do read
                }
            }

            // Update progress by setting current iteration as current value
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progressBar.Value = i); // 1/10, 2/10, 3/10 etc...
        }
    });
}
```

Example 2 (calculating progress percentage):

```
private void YourButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> sqlQueries = new List<string>(10);

    // DO NOT CHANGE maximum value of your progress bar
    // progressBar.MaxValue = sqlQueries.Count;
    progressBar.Value = 0; // Reset current value to 0

    // Run loop in other thread
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sqlQueries.Count; i++)
        {
            string sqlQuery = sqlQueries[i];

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    // Do read
                }
            }

            // Calculate a simple percentage
            int progressPercentage = (int)Math.Round(i * 100 / sqlQueries.Count);
            // Update progress with calculated percentage
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progressBar.Value = progressPercentage); // 10%, 20%, 30% etc...
        }
    });
}
```